# How do i draw image inside onComplete method?

Tags: android, facebook

I have following scenario: After a user is successfully authenticated via facebook credentials some image appears on the screen and clicking on it will post the url of the image as well as some text to the facebook wall.

For this i am referring the example given in facebook documentation. Under facebook.authorize onComplete method i want to draw some images. I have added the following code:

```
 public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(MyGreatActivity.this);
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("img1", "drawable", getPackageName());
            imgView.setImageResource(id);
 }
```

But when i ran the example after successful authentication no image appears.

Please guide me on this

Thanks,

Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ImageView to the layout, e.g.

```
myLinearLayout.addView (imgView);
```

Comment: Hi aleadam thanks for replying can you please tell me how can i know the name of layout as you have mentioned myLinearLayout

Comment: @Pankaj I suggest you to read carefully the Android Dev Guide, specially the UI part: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: i have studied and added following code :        LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
myLayout.addView(imgView);                                            But when i ran this it shows the application has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: You will need to read the logcat to see what's wrong. Please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html and the pages therein (most importantly "Using DDMS")

Answer (score 0):

create Layoutparams for ur Imageview, then set that params to ur imageview
hope this work

Comment: @hotveryspicy thanks for replying can you post url of some example

Comment: imgView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
myLinearLayout.addView (imgView);